# How can I save scores from wordpress quiz?

Tags: wordpress

I have investigated several Wordpress plugins for taking and scoring quizzes and all seem pretty good. But none appears to store the scores with userid. I need to restrict access to certain pages of my site until after a user has passed my quiz. Can anyone recommend a plugin/process for doing this?

Comment: That sounds fun. Which plugins are your favorite and I'll write a patch for one of them. The only modifications that would have to be made are the visitor would have to be logged in to take the quiz, then we attach the user id to the quiz results, Then for the post that you need to restrict, just check to see if there is a set of quiz results that have the user id attached and score greater than X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing something slightly different. I am just patching one of the plugins to update the user's role.